Slack bolt's compatibility with Java 21
I'm working with a new project based on Java 21 that uses the latest bolt version "1.39.3" for dependencies com.slack.api:bolt, com.slack.api:bolt-servlet, com.slack.api:bolt-socket-mode.
I am getting the following stacktrace
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'slackApp' defined in class path resource [com/rakuten/microservice/infra/configuration/SlackAppConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.slack.api.bolt.App]: Factory method 'slackApp' threw exception with message: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at com.rakuten.microservice.MicroserviceApplication.main(MicroserviceApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.slack.api.bolt.App]: Factory method 'slackApp' threw exception with message: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
    at com.slack.api.Slack.socketMode(Slack.java:174)
    at com.slack.api.bolt.socket_mode.SocketModeApp.lambda$buildSocketModeClientFactory$2(SocketModeApp.java:76)
    at com.slack.api.bolt.socket_mode.SocketModeApp.run(SocketModeApp.java:187)
    at com.slack.api.bolt.socket_mode.SocketModeApp.start(SocketModeApp.java:177)
    at com.rakuten.microservice.infra.configuration.SlackAppConfiguration.slackApp(SlackAppConfiguration.java:22)
    at com.rakuten.microservice.infra.configuration.SlackAppConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$slackApp$0(<generated>)
    at com.rakuten.microservice.infra.configuration.SlackAppConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:339)
    at com.rakuten.microservice.infra.configuration.SlackAppConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.slackApp(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 36 common frames omitted

So this looks like Bolt is looking for javax classes, and is therefore not compatible with Java 21 (which has the jakarta namespace).
Is my understanding correct? How do I work with Bolt and Java 21?

Following their official documentation with references to Example apps with Spring Boot and further its sample code for spring-boot-3 under the build.gradle. I could figure it out and verify that the dependency that you need(sharing Maven construct) would be:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.slack.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>bolt-jakarta-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.39.3</version>
</dependency>


Quoting further from the bolt-socket-mode, the dependencies required would be:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.slack.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>bolt</artifactId>
  <version>1.39.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.slack.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>bolt-socket-mode</artifactId>
  <version>1.39.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version> <!-- this should help you-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
  <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>


Thanks for looking into this.
I assume this fixes the bolt-servlet javax dependency, but the bolt-socket-mode also depends directly on javax.websocket » javax.websocket-api, see  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.slack.api/bolt-socket-mode/1.39.3

@ArnaudJeansen Updated the answer with relevant dependencies required for the bolt-socket-mode.

Thanks @naman
I went with the other websocket implementation:
SocketModeApp socketModeApp = new SocketModeApp(slackAppProperties.getAppToken(), SocketModeClient.Backend.JavaWebSocket, app);
With dependencies
com.slack.api:bolt-jakarta-servlet, com.slack.api:bolt-socket-mode, org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.1
I also excluded javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api from under the socket-mode dep, just in case.
It starts properly now.
Thanks a lot!
